# PHP I want it to give me the correct information related to the user

Tags: php, mysqli, phpmyadmin

I have a Session open with a User thats already logged in, i've tested that it gives me the user associated with the current session

Im asking for help on i want the form/data to only show me information related to the user  so instead of it giving me everyone's order as a list, i want it to only give me information related to who the user is

Here is the portion of the code that has the issue
Where am i going wrong i know fetch assoc either does get the data but im not sure if im using it correctly

This was the code for testing that the user has connected, it showed the correct user is this impacting anything?

```
<?php if (isset($_SESSION['username'])) : ?>
<div class="input-group">
<label>Username: </label>
<strong><?php echo $_SESSION['username']; ?></strong></p>
</div>
<?php endif ?>
```

This is the code of the session im trying to connect

```
<?php
$name = $_SESSION['username'];
//$query = "SELECT * FROM 'confirm' WHERE username='$name';";
$sql = "SELECT food, tablenum FROM confirm";
$result = $db->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
// output data of each row
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo "<br> username: ". $row["username"]. "Food: ". $row["food"]. "Table Number: " . $row["tablenum"] . "<br>";
}
 } else {
  echo "0 results";
 }
 ?>
```

Comment: In your commented out query (the one I'm guessing you're trying to get to work), `confirm` should not have single quotes around it. Either use backticks `\`confirm\`` or no quotes at all.

Comment: well as @aynber said you need the query with where condition. Also you have not added username column in select columns and used it in echo statement below

Comment: Thank you two for the help, i was able to fix it to a certain degree, if i could say both your answers were correct i would but here in the comments i cant sorry

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
session_start();  // You need to start session
$name = $_SESSION['username'];
//$query = "SELECT * FROM 'confirm' WHERE username='$name';";
$sql = "SELECT food, tablenum FROM confirm";
$result = $db->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
// output data of each row
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo "<br> username: ". $row["username"]. "Food: ". $row["food"]. "Table Number: " . $row["tablenum"] . "<br>";
}
 } else {
  echo "0 results";
 }
 ?>
```

Comment: its already in the session if i add that it gives me A session had already been started - ignoring session_start()